# Выбрать последовательность элементов большой коллекции, которая совпадает с другой последовательностью

Tags: c#, linq

Нужно получить **последовательность** (подколлекцию) из большой коллекции:

```
 List<Word> words
```

в которой свойства с типом string поочередно совпадают с элементами типа string другой коллекции:

```
words[1].Name  
words[2].Name == names[1]  
words[3].Name == names[2]  
words[4].Name == names[3]  
words[5].Name
```

...
На выходе тогда получается список из 3 элементов Word. Как это проще сделать?

Comment: А что делать, если нету совпадающего элемента? Если например `names[2]` в списке нет вообще? Или если есть, но в самом начале списка?

Comment: Должны совпасть все элементы из маленькой коллекции. Если нет, то null возвратить, например.

Comment: А если не тот порядок?

Comment: И порядок должен совпасть.

Comment: @Maksim, принципиально использование linq?

Comment: @Grundy нет, не принципиально.

Comment: возможны ли дырки? например: `words[2].Name == names[1]`, `words[5].Name == names[2]`, `words[15].Name == names[3]`?

Comment: @Grundy нет, нужно именно совпадение последовательности найти.

Answer (score 2):

Ну например так:

```
static IEnumerable<Word> Filter(IEnumerable<Word> words, IEnumerable<string> names)
{
    using (var nameEnum = names.GetEnumerator())
    using (var wordEnum = words.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (nameEnum.MoveNext())
        {
            bool found = false;
            while (wordEnum.MoveNext())
            {
                if (wordEnum.Current.Name == nameEnum.Current)
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
                throw new ApplicationException("Cannot find matching pair");
            yield return wordEnum.Current;
        }
    }
}

static IEnumerable<Word> FilterOrNull(IEnumerable<Word> words, IEnumerable<string> names)
{
    try
    {
        return Filter(words, names).ToList();
    }
    catch (ApplicationException ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Хитрость задачи в том, что вам нужно обходить *две* последовательности одновременно, наподобие того, как это делает `Enumerable.Zip`.

---

Окей, если искать нужно только значения *подряд*, нужно делать по-другому.

```
static IEnumerable<Word> FilterWords(IEnumerable<Word> words, IEnumerable<string> names)
{
    using (var nameEnum = names.GetEnumerator())
    using (var wordEnum = words.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!nameEnum.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        bool foundFirst = false;
        while (wordEnum.MoveNext())
        {
            if (wordEnum.Current.Name == nameEnum.Current)
            {
                foundFirst = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!foundFirst)
            throw new ApplicationException("Cannot find matching pair");

        yield return wordEnum.Current;

        while (nameEnum.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!wordEnum.MoveNext() || wordEnum.Current.Name != nameEnum.Current)
                throw new ApplicationException("Cannot find matching pair");
            yield return wordEnum.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

Функция `FilterOrNull` такая же.

---

Для случая, если начальный кусок может повторяться (например, `words = {"1", "2", "1", "2", "3"}`, `names = {"1", "2", "3"}`), вам по сути нужен поиск подстроки в строке (только «буквами» являются строки, а «текстом» — последовательность строк). Для этого используйте либо простой квадратичный поиск (пропуская по одному начальные элементы `words`), или воспользуйтесь одним из (более сложных, но и более эффективных) [алгоритмов поиска подстроки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8).

Comment: эх :-) а я обычными `for` хотел :-) Можно сделать чуть более общее решение с генериками и передачей функции которая вернет свойство которое надо будет сравнивать :)

Comment: Если дыры не разрешаются, сейчас поправлю.

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, в условии не было сказано, что можно индексировать. Поэтому пришлось извращаться.

Comment: кстати, интересный вопрос найдет ли `{1,2,3}` если будет идти `{1,2,1,2,3}`?

Comment: @Grundy: У меня — нет.

Comment: @Grundy: Для случая, когда возможны такие вот ситуации, по сути нам нужно найти подстроку в строке (только «буквами» выступают строки). Для этого существуют готовые алгоритмы типа [КМП](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9A%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B0), но они достаточно сложные.

Comment: ага, но возможно таких ситуаций в задаче не предусматривается :)

Comment: @Grundy: Поскольку это важно, перенёс в ответ.

Comment: @VladD _"если начальный кусок может повторяться"_ -- в такой ситуации можно использовать Windowed. добавил в [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489236/196972)

Comment: @Stack: Интересно, чем отличается `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.Windowed` от [`Morelinq.MoreEnumerable.Windowed`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Windowed.cs)?

Comment: @VladD _"чем отличается Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.Windowed от Morelinq.MoreEnumerable.Windowed?"_ -- не знаю. о Morelinq только сейчас узнал. а Microsoft.FSharp ставится вместе с Visual Studio и .NET

Comment: @Stack: MoreLinq написал (по крайней мере 1-ую версию) сам [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) (так что это как бы знак качества).

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

static int indexOf(IEnumerable<string> ws, IEnumerable<string> ns) {
    var nf = ns.First();
    var rs = ws.Select((w, i) => new { w, i })
               .SkipWhile(wi => nf != wi.w)
               .Zip(ns, (wi, n) => new { wi.i, eq = wi.w == n })
               .ToList();
    var f = rs.FirstOrDefault();
    return f != null && rs.All(r => r.eq) ? f.i : -1;
}
```

---

Результат

```
var words = new[] { "", "", "", "", "", "", "w1", "w2", "w3", "w4", "w5" };
var names = new[] { "w1", "w2", "w3" };
var i = indexOf(words, names);      // i == 6
if(i > -1) return names;
```

---

```
var names = new[] { "w11", "w2", "w3" };
var i = indexOf(words, names);      // i == -1
```

---

**UPDATE**

*"Для случая, если начальный кусок может повторяться (например, words = {"1", "2", "1", "2", "3"}, names = {"1", "2", "3"})"*

```
// #r "FSharp.Core"
bool Contains(IEnumerable<string> words, IEnumerable<string> names) {
    return Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule
           .Windowed(names.Count(), words)
           .FirstOrDefault(g => g.SequenceEqual(names)) != null;
}
var words = new[] { "", "", "", "", "", "", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "", "", "" };
var names = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };
Contains(words, names)   // true
```

Comment: Ваш первый метод исходит из того, что коллекцию _можно_ обойти дважды. По модулю этого изящно, да.

Comment: @VladD _"Ваш первый метод исходит из того, что коллекцию можно обойти дважды"_ --  да. но ns можно ToList(). и во втором методе тоже лучше сделать names.ToList()

Comment: Угу, я обычно так и делаю. (Но это тоже не идеально, т. к. исходит из того, что последовательность `ns` конечная.)

Comment: похожий вопрос для sql server - [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/489302/196972)