# Поиск последовательности в таблице

Tags: sql-server

В БД есть таблица в два столбца с большим количеством записей. Первый столбец - id, второй - числа с плавающей точкой.

Дана последовательность трёх чисел с плавающей точкой. Нужно узнать, встречается ли такая последовательность в БД - допустим с 10 id по 12. Если есть - то нужен id начального числа.

Как это лучше всего сделать с наименьшими энергозатратами? Выбрать в массив вхождения по первому числу и в затем цикле проверить остальные 2? Но записей в ней очень много - такая переборка займёт большое время.

Дополню, чтобы понятней задача была. Вот БД:

1. 4.3422
2. 5.3434
3. 3.3243
4. 4.2453
5. 2.3445
   и т.д.

Дана последовательность 3х чисел: 5.3434, 3.3243, 4.2453. Нужно найти эту последовательность в базе данных - есть ли она вообще, а если есть, то вернуть что они находятся в том же порядке со 2 id по 4.

Comment: В каком смысле энергозатратами? В смысле чтобы поменьше писать кода, или чтобы было эффективно?

Comment: Кроме того, порядок строк в базе данных не определён. Поэтому говорить о «последовательности» особого смысла нет.

Comment: там несколько десятков миллионов записей, и выборка по первому числу получается такая увесистая)) Можно ли это одним запросом решить?

Comment: Окей, значит, нужна эффективность, то есть выполнение на уровне базы. Но остаётся вопрос с порядком. Последовательность строк — это при какой-то конкретной сортировке?

Comment: Они в базе по порядку идут. Каждая строчка имеет айди и число. Данная последовательность из 3х чисел должна соответствовать последовательности в БД. Чтобы первое число было таким же как в 10 (id) строчке, второе - в 11, третье в 12.

Comment: Не, у записей в базе без order by нет никакого предопределённого порядка. Посмотрите в ответ — там везде `ORDER BY Id`, например. И это не просто так.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Стандартная задача на поиск подпоследовательности в последовательности.
Далее два запроса, которые ищут все вхождения подпоследовательности в последовательность:

1) вариант для подпосл. из 3х элементов. работает только если в Id нет пропусков значений.

2) для любых подпоследовательностей.

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE(Id INT, Value MONEY)
DECLARE @T2 TABLE(Id INT, Value MONEY)
INSERT @T1 VALUES
(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,3),
(6,2),(7,3),(8,4),(9,3),(10,2)
INSERT @T2 VALUES
(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)

--вариант для трёх, работает только если в Id нет пропусков значений.
SELECT MIN(T1.Id) Id
FROM @T1 T1
  JOIN @T2 T2 ON T1.Value = T2.Value
GROUP BY T1.Id - T2.Id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3

--более общий вариант, работает с любыми последовательностями
SELECT MIN(T1.Id) Id
FROM
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Id)N,* FROM @T1)T1
  JOIN
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Id)N,COUNT(*)OVER()C,* FROM @T2)T2
  ON T1.Value = T2.Value
GROUP BY T1.N - T2.N
HAVING COUNT(*)=MAX(C)
```

**UPD**: если вы заранее знаете все три значения, то пожалуй лучше встроить конструктор таблицы прямо в запрос. Ещё 2 варианта:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE(Id INT, Value MONEY)
INSERT @T1 VALUES
(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,3),
(6,2),(7,3),(8,4),(9,3),(10,2)
DECLARE
  @Param1 MONEY = 2,
  @Param2 MONEY = 3,
  @Param3 MONEY = 4

--В столбце Id таблички @T1 нет пропусков:
SELECT MIN(T1.Id) Id
FROM @T1 T1 JOIN
  (VALUES(1,@Param1),(2,@Param2),(3,@Param3))T2(Id, Value)
  ON T1.Value = T2.Value
GROUP BY T1.Id - T2.Id
HAVING COUNT(*)=3

--В столбце Id таблички @T1 есть пропуски:
SELECT MIN(T1.Id) Id
FROM
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Id)N,* FROM @T1)T1
  JOIN
  (VALUES(1,@Param1),(2,@Param2),(3,@Param3))T2(N, Value)
  ON T1.Value = T2.Value
GROUP BY T1.N - T2.N
HAVING COUNT(*)=3
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Поставил бы плюс, да рейтинг не позволяет.

Comment: @Vlad, так поставьте галочку, что ответ принят:) Чуть ниже плюсов/минусов.

Comment: Век живи - век учись :)

Comment: @Vlad, кстати работает даже если подпоследовательности "накладываются" друг на друга. Т.е. последовательность 121 найдётся в 1212121 три раза, не смотря на то что LEN('121')*3 > LEN('1212121')